# Is there a different relation between Kaede and Sia?

Tags: shuffle

In the last episode of Shuffle, while the end theme song was rolling with credits, there was a scene where Kaede and Sia were together and then they crashed into something falling over each other and accidentally "kissed". Their expression was toooo "different" so? Do they have or grew a romantic relation?[image: The scene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the game, that scene is anime original (it doesn't happen in the visual novel, which is the source material). It is also quite irrelevant as they literally kiss accidentally. You can call it fanservice, nowadays anime/VNs include that even among straight girls.
In the visual novel there are no yuri relationships of any kind.

This question was posed in steam a few months ago. Of course the person answering says the same that I'm telling you now.

http://steamcommunity.com/app/537100/discussions/0/135507548127544499/

Answer (score 1):

Because this scene is **anime-only**, there isn't any reference from the VN to know any further. Maybe the anime production crew know about this, but the official information available does not tell anything more about this event.

So the answer probably is 'There isn't official information to support this, so probably they do not'